# display X over img

Tags: html, css, image

I want to display a X over the img in css.  However I don't want the X to be text, I want it to be lines.  From the top left to the bottom right and from the bottom left to the top right.

My goal is that this looks like images on some photo sites so that you can't copy them.  I'm fine if people copy my images, but I want it to have the line over it.  The reason I want this is I have a page that has Achievements and I want the ones that aren't unlocked to look this way.  (Although I've done everything besides the css on the img.  So don't try to do extra work for nothing.)

If you feel like there is maybe a better look than a X that suits it's purpose then please comment it down below.

here is my html part:

```
<div id="posB">
    <div class="container">
        <span>
            <img id="3141cli" src="3141cli.png" />
            <span>Unlock at 3,141 clicks.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <img id="10000cli" src="10000cli.png" />
            <span>Unlock at 10,000 clicks.</span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <img id="25000cli" src="25000cli.png" />
            <span>Unlock at 25,000 clicks.</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my css part:

```
#posB {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 55px;
}
.container span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* Adjust if multi-line text */
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 120px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container span img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    opacity: 0.45;
}
.container span span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

*Thank you!*

Comment: What kind of code did you have for the `myClassName`

Comment: Assume I have nothing please.  I know this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Use an svg X and then overlay that on top. It will be crisp no matter what size it is. Please post the code you have tried and we can then help much more effectivley.

Comment: The reason this question was downvoted is because you need to try something first. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like the following:

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yRxgmd).

```
<div>
  <div class="line-1"></div>
  <div class="line-2"></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>

div {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.line-1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  top: -12%;
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
.line-2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  top: -12%;
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
}
```